# Why is glossy shader adding pink in cycles?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, materials

All my shaders using gloss are mysteriously adding pink, textures are not missing, and the glossy shaders without textures have the pink issue as well. When I disconnect the gloss shader, the pink goes away.

Anyone seen this before? I included an image of one of the materials, silver below. (I reduced the setup see what was causing pink and narrowed it down to glossy) When glossy, is disconnected, pink goes away.

Also, noticed in the preview window, the material shows as it should, unfortunately, the pink shows in the render.

[image: with gloss]

[image: withoutgloss]

Comment: Could show a screenshot of the material actually on an object eg Suzanne or a sphere.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nevermind! so I checked/unchecked "Use Nodes" and the pink went away.